# Whenever I run a CPU intensive process, my system restarts

Tags: cpu, motherboard, power-supply

I've noticed this when I try to calculate the inverse of a 10,000 x 10,000 random matrix with Matlab or Octave. My computer just restarts without prompting any error message. I have already looked for similar issues on various forums with no success.

I've already proven that this is not related with memory usage since matrix inversion has a space complexity of O(n^2) and a time complexity of O(n^3). Memtest showed no RAM failures. Surely it is not due to the CPU temperature because this happens very suddenly. I suspect this may be related to the power supply.

I'm running Ubuntu 15.04 (64-bit) on an Intel Core i7-4790K, 2x8GB RAM Kingston Fury, Asus Z97-P motherboard, NVIDIA 980 GTX gpu, and Corsair CX750M power supply. Still have not tried this with Windows.

Comment: its likely either heat or power. if you install and config `lm-sensors` do your sensors show a reasonable temperature under the load?

Comment: When I try to reproduce the error there is not enough time (about 2 secs) to run the command to check the sensors, but the idle readings seem fine (32°C).

Comment: journalctl --boot=-1 should give you last boots system-log on systemd-based systems. Just lookup at the end of the log, maybe there's some useful stuff

Comment: What you have described is a high wattage rig, between your CPU and GPU. you may want to consider a higher wattage power supply if your power config can cause a blackscreen.

Answer (score 0):

Me from the past: after 6 months having this issue, we finally found the real cause and solved it. The power consumption of the motherboard was configured for optimal performance, it just needed to be switched back to normal. Now I can invert big matrices with no trouble at all.

Comment: Seems an odd definition of optimal performance. I guess it crashes harder and faster than normal.